# Is there a site that provides (legal) online access to free chess books?

Tags: learning, books, online

As the title says, is there a site that provides (legal) online access to free chess books?

Answer (score 7):

[Open Chess Books](http://www.openchessbooks.org/) is a site that aims to “republish classic chess books, with all diagrams transformed in animated boards, and release them for free.”

They only have two books at the moment (*Modern Ideas in Chess* and *Chess Fundamentals*), but it's a great resource so far.

[Predator at the Chessboard](http://www.chesstactics.org) by Ward Farnsworth is a great primer on chess tactics that's available to read for free online or purchase in print form.

Answer (score 3):

The Internet Archive is probably the largest repository of free ebooks. Project Gutenberg has old classics by Staunton, Bird, Ed Lasker and Capablanca.